# Unable to Access Page Error

Tags: error, url, parameters

I am trying to edit the `Probability` value in the `Stage` field on the `Opportunity` Sobject, but when I click save it gives me the following error:

> The value of a parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.

Comment: Do you have a Roll-up Summary field summarizing a currency field on the opportunity object and Advanced Currency Management enabled?

Comment: @cmmoutes13 indeed I have these 2 enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs when there is an invalid Rollup Summary Field on the opportunity object that is summarizing a currency field and the instance also has Advanced Currency Management enabled. Currency Rollup Summary Fields are not supported by Advanced Currency Management.

> Resolutions: Disable the Rollup Summary Field OR disable Advanced
>   Currency Management.

Please see the following [link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176364&language=en_US) for more information.